# Google APAC 2017 Round A - incorrect

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was wondering whether anyone could offer some help reviewing the code below? I tried the Google APAC 2017 Round A but was traped by the FIRST question, whose link is https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/11274486/dashboard.

In fact, I had some outputs and they all seem to be correct, while the online judge not saying so. It would be highly appreciated if anyone is willing to scan through the code and have some discussion. Thanks!

```
string A()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    cin.get();
    string leader, cur;
    int i = 0, j = 0, L = 0, leaderLetterNum = 0;
    set<char> letters;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, cur);
        L = cur.empty() ? 0 : cur.length();
        for(j = 0; j < L; ++j)
        {
            if(cur[j] >= 'A' && cur[j] <= 'Z') letters.insert(cur[j]);
        }
        if(leader.empty() || letters.size() > leaderLetterNum)
        {
            leader.clear();
            leader = cur;
            leaderLetterNum = letters.size();
        }
        cur.clear();
        letters.clear();
    }
    return leader;
}

void multiTest()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    int caseCount = 0;
    while(caseCount++ < T)
    {
        cout << "Case #" << caseCount << ": " << A() << endl;
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    multiTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the condition

> If there is a tie, the person whose name comes earliest in alphabetical order is the leader.

Try using

```
if(leader.empty() || letters.size() > leaderLetterNum ||
(letters.size() == leaderLetterNum && cur < leader))
```

instead of

```
if(leader.empty() || letters.size() > leaderLetterNum)
```